# Running multiple instances of Netbeans under the same user

Tags: java, netbeans

If a user logs into two different computers on a (Windows) network and launches netbeans on both of them, the error below pops up. Is there a way to resolve this so that two different PCs on the network can both run netbeans under the same account?

I would like three programming students to share the same working directory to make it easy for them to collaborate. An easy way to achieve this is to have the three students on a team all log into windows under the same user account.

My school will be hosting a programming competition where students work in teams of three, so I thought this would be an easy way to minimize the number of temporary windows accounts we need to create. Is there a work-around?

[image: Error Msg - An instance of the program seems to be already running]

Comment: this is not how to do collaboration, git is how to do collaboration

Comment: Or almost any other version controlled software. Mercurial for instance.
However, If you're TRULY looking for an editor that more than one can use at the same time. (Don't know why you would want that) there's a site called cloud9.io (http://c9.io) It's alright for small apps or test code.

Comment: This is for an ICPC style competition. Students cannot go online. But git through netbeans might be an option.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the direct question:  *probably* with some finagling of directories, but most definitely **not** worth the trouble.

If we're talking about students working in teams, then there are several approaches to this:

- Let the students work on one box with one driver (person typing), always keeping what they need to do in mind.  This is generally reserved for pair programming, since more than two people can get a bit crowded, but depending on the amount of work to do and their relative skill levels, it can be beneficial.
- Let the students work on their own box and have them communicate their changes through a source control system, like Git, on a hosted (either internally or externally) service such as GitHub or Bitbucket.  They don't have to crowd over the same machine to get things done, and each person will be able to contribute in their own time.
- Let the students work on any box and have them work on a web-based IDE service, like [Cloud9](http://c9.io).  They'll have to do a little more setup to get the project to compile Java-based systems, but the real benefit of that is that the code doesn't need to be pulled down locally - it'll all remain in the cloud.